# How to pass a javascript string variable to a django view?

Tags: jquery, json, django, push-notification, python-requests

This is the javascript part. The following **store_token** function is being called from this file and a string value eg "AasdfGth:Jl-Hjf...." is passed (browser token value)

```
function store_token(token) {

    var data = {'reg_id':token};
    console.log("Reg id", data);
    data = JSON.stringify(data);
    $.post('/api_call_for_django_view', data, function(response){});
};
```

The django view is -

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def api_call_for_django_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        token = request.POST.dict()
        print("", token)    #this gives a value {'{"reg_id":{}}': ''}
        registration_id = token['reg_id']
```

Don't know why the token value is not passed while it reaches the **store_token** function successfully!

```
console.log("Reg id", data);
```

gives the following value
[image]

I want the `reg_id` string value i.e. `token` from javascript to get stored in to `registration_id` variable of django view

Comment: What happens if you post 'data' directly as object rather than doing JSON.stringify(data) in your JS function?

Comment: as @SohelAman pointed out you don't need to stringily and sending data as object might solve your issue though it doesn't answer why there is and empty object in POST. does this ```console.log("Reg id", data);``` output correct data?

Comment: @SohelAman The data passes successfully to the django view but when I try to print `request.POST` it shows `<QueryDict: {}>` and `request.POST.dict()` returns empty python dictionary. Is it the right way to access the object ?

Comment: @mursalin Yes the output gives the correct `reg_id` that is required. The form in which it prints in the console is attached to the question. The value `"fEZBO4u ..."` is the token value

Comment: @AmitPathak, is ```token``` a promise? if yes, then that might be the problem. It should be json serializable to send as data.

Comment: @mursalin Yes, rightly pointed out by you. It is a promise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mursalin pointed out, the `token` variable in is an instance of Promise. The string data will be available when the promise is resolved. So, in your JS, you have to make the post request when the promise is resolved. See the following JS code,

```js
function store_token(token) {
    if (token instanceof Promise) {
        token.then(tokenData => {
            console.log('tokenData', tokenData);
            let data = { 'reg_id': tokenData };
            console.log("data", data);
            // data = JSON.stringify(data);
            $.post('/api_call_for_django_view', data, response => { console.log('post response', response); });
        }).catch(tokenError => {
            console.log('tokenError', tokenError);
        });
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I implemented it exactly in this manner and it is working !